# how to actually make a call, not display a number, on android 6

Tags: android

using intent of CALL and the permission. it works on android 5 on samsung galaxy s4. and it makes a phone call when i press a button in my activity. however on android 6, Samsung j7 , it just displays a number.

how to make it do the call?

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode==this.requestCode_permission_CALL_PHONE)
        {
            if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + this.getString(R.string.phone_number)));
                        this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("permission","permission grant ignored by user");
                    //requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public int requestCode_permission_CALL_PHONE=1001;

    public void doCall(View v) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE} , this.requestCode_permission_CALL_PHONE);
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + this.getString(R.string.phone_number)));
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: set runtime permission

Comment: added code ....

Comment: you can check in `Setting > Apps > Select your App > Permissions > Grant permission for Phone`. Now again test your App.

Answer (score 0):

There is concept of permission manager/ Security manager in some devices like Xiomi, Redmi and even some devices of Samsung. Please check if you have that device.
if not you can set runtime permissions correctly.